# How do I define a structure with a list using a specific size

Tags: c#, list, .net-4.0, marshalling

Looking at the example below, TestPropSix is an array with 5 elements.  How do I Marshal that array to set a constant specific length on the strings inside?  Say I want each string in the array to also only allow a size of 100.  I think I have Marshaled the array correctly it's just the strings in the array that worry me.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct TestStructTwo
{
    public int TestPropOne;

    public int TestPropTwo;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
    public string TestPropThree;

    public int TestPropFour;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
    public string TestPropFive;

    //How do I set the STRING elements as having a limit of 100
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.ByValTStr)]
    public string[] TestPropSix;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
    public string TestPropSeven;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an array instead of a list?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen tell me you're not the downvote...  Downvotes are for bad questions, what on earth would make mine a "bad" question?  There is no reason an array could not be used (though lists are easier to work with).  If needed I can use an array, will you please suggest an answer either way?  Thanks